# Sveltkit reposting uploaded file

Tags: file-upload, sveltekit

I have a Svelte page (`+page.svelte`) that posts a file to a server page:

```html
<form method="POST" action="?/process_list" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
</form>
```

the server page (`+page.server.ts`) is supposed to grab that file and push it on to a different endpoint . .

```js
process_list: async ({ cookies, request }) => {
    const data = await request.formData();
    const uploadfile = data.get('file');

    const bytes = new Uint8Array(await uploadfile.arrayBuffer());
    let newfile = new Blob([bytes], { type: uploadfile.type });
    
    //I GET THESE LOGS - I CAN SEE THE FILE CONTENTS 
    console.log(newfile)
    console.log(await newfile.text())

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(
        "file",
        newfile
    );


    try {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/calculate_bulk', {
                method: 'POST',
                body:  formData
            }
        )
        const blob = await res.blob();
        console.log(await blob.text())
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
```

The new endpoint is running a cherrypy server (which I verified works correctly).  But when I post to that new endpoint (calculate_bulk), I get a response:

> TypeError: Service.calculate_bulk() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file'

Which seems to suggest that the file is not coming through?  This is definitely something with the way that sveltekit is doing the reposting - I can see the file contents in the upload function, but the file never makes its way to the server.  I don't think this is an issue with cherrypy because that service (and this endpoint) is being used by others just fine.